memnet package: Error in if (class(adj) != "igraph") { :condition has length > 1
I try to use memnet package in R (https://rdrr.io/cran/memnet/f/vignettes/memnet.Rmd).
I have a problem with the function: network_plot(grow_st())
When I use network_plot(grow_st(20, 2), I get:

Error in if (class(adj) != "igraph") { :the condition has length > 1

What goes wrong? How to fix it?

possible solution: 1) library(igraph); 2) g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix((grow_st(20, 2)), mode = "undirected"); 3) plot(g)
